# How to use a conditonal update using cases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, case

```
Case when oldvalue
like 'val1','val2','val3'
then newvalue = 'newVal1'
Case when oldvalue
like 'val4'
then newvalue = newvalue  + 'newval2'
else
newvalue = newalue  + 'othernewval'
```

Then I would need to update this query

```
update  table
set oldvalue = newvalue
where condition
```

I don't know how to write this query in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Please put the actual query you're working with along with some sample data. As it is written it is very hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your question body specifies SQL Server 2008 and your tag specifies SQL Server 2008R2. Even though they have similar names they are different versions. Please edit your question to make it clear which version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You'd likely need to write this something like:

```
UPDATE Table
SET oldvalue = 
    CASE WHEN oldvalue = 'val1'
        OR oldvalue = 'val2'
        OR oldvalue = 'val3'
        THEN 'newVal1'
    WHEN oldvalue = 'val4'
        THEN oldvalue  + 'newval2'
    ELSE
        oldvalue + 'othernewval'
    END
WHERE condition;
```

In order to get a really good answer, you need to provide a good question with all the necessary details.  Please read [help us help you](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/) for some guidelines about how to write a good question, then press the [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/135074/edit) button under your question and add the details there.